# Similar Triangles, Ratios and Proportions, Similar Polygons

Tags: geometry

[image]

to find out the answers for i & ii and for iii if its either a postulate or theorem and the answer.
for B) to find the distance and the rest on has the questions on it and also the first ones to. 
please answer my question as soon as possible